# orthogonal vector from a vector and a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a vector $V1$, another vector $V2$, and a Matrix $M$, if I want $V2$ to be orthogonal to $V1$ I have to use Gram-Schmidt $$V2'=V2-\frac{V1.V2}{V1.V1}*V1$$ if I want V2 to be **M-Orthogonal** to V1 I use $$V2'=V2-(transpose(V1)*M*V2)*V1$$

what I want to get is combination of both characteristics above, i.e. I want $V2$ to be **orthogonal AND M-Orthogonal** to $V1$ at the same time how should I do that?

Comment: if you want to span the same space as $\{V1, V2 \}$, then it is not possible in general. $V1$ and $MV1$ need to be linearly dependent.

Comment: I'm assuming $M$ is symmetric positive definite and by M-orthogonal, you mean $V_1^T M V_2' = 0$? If so, I believe your second formula should be $V_2' =  V_2 - \frac{V_1^TMV_2}{V_1^TMV_1} \cdot V_1$.